# How to change this sql query into derived table?

Tags: sql-server

This is the original query

```
SELECT
    YEAR(o.order_date) AS year,
    COUNT(i.order_id) AS total
FROM 
    sales.order_items AS i
INNER JOIN 
    sales.orders AS o ON i.order_id = o.order_id
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(o.order_date)
```

This is what I've done so far

```
SELECT
    YEAR(time) AS year,
    SUM(price) AS total
FROM 
    (SELECT
         YEAR (o.order_date) AS time,
         SUM (i.quantity * i.list_price) AS price
     FROM 
         sales.order_items AS i
     INNER JOIN 
         sales.orders AS o ON i.order_id = o.order_id) AS derived
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(time)
ORDER BY 
    YEAR(time)
```

I get this error:

> Column 'sales.orders.order_date' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: you missed the `GROUP BY` in the inner query

Comment: If you wanted to do the `GROUP BY` in the outer query, remove the `SUM` from the inner query

Comment: Okay....I got it. Thankss

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT
year,
SUM(price) AS total
FROM (
   SELECT
   YEAR (o.order_date) AS year,
   SUM (i.quantity * i.list_price) AS price
   FROM sales.order_items AS i
   JOIN sales.orders AS o
     ON i.order_id = o.order_id
   GROUP BY YEAR (o.order_date) 
) AS derived
GROUP BY year
```

But I think this gives the same result:

```
SELECT
YEAR (o.order_date) AS year,
SUM (i.quantity * i.list_price) AS price
FROM sales.order_items AS i
JOIN sales.orders AS o
  ON i.order_id = o.order_id
GROUP BY YEAR (o.order_date)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. that works well.

Comment: I got new question after trying to understand the query. Why can't I just write **price** instead of **SUM(price) AS total** ? What's the different with the **year** ? Thx

Comment: @Emthosin If you changed `sum(price)` to `price`, the outer query would be doing nothing. Actually, I think it's doing nothing now, because `year` is unique from the inner query due to the `group by` there, so grouping again by year will do nothing to the output of the inner query.

Comment: the sum is already done in the inner query and that's confusing me. It's like doing sum twice. But, if I only type price in the outer query, it will be error. Hmmm....